# NodeJS stops responding after 11 requests

Tags: node.js

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
console.log("New request :"+request.url);
var found = false;
for(var i= 0; i < requests.length; i++){
    match = requests[i];
    if(match.method == request.method && request.url.match(match.regexp))
    {
        console.log("Matched request: "+match.url);
        pg.connect(databaseUrl, function(error, client) {
            if(error)
                processError(response, error);
            else
                match.action(client, request, response);
        });
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found)
    processError(response, "Request url does not exist: "+request.url);
}).listen(3000);
sys.puts("Server running... waiting for requests");
```

Hi everyone. I'm stuck with this code. Whenever I call 11 times the same request, nodejs stops responding and does not even logs "New request: "+request.url.
Anyone has an idea of what's going on ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't see anything in this part of the code but that is really inefficient.  You should use a hash rather than iterating an array to decide if an action matches - its O(1) instead of O(n)!

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Indeed it could be much more efficient. But it's not a priority for the moment. I just need a "stable" server and really don't understand this behavior (no error from the server).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code that I can see - I would look for problems in your db handling or match handling...

Comment: Ok you were right. Actually, the pg.connect does not call the handler after some queries. Still figuring out what's going on.

Comment: Do you need to run pg.connect in a loop?

Comment: Ok so it seems there is a bug in node-postgres. When you run an http request and do a pg.connect, if you do not query on postgres in the request,the client pooling gets broken. (I was directly returning simulated values so there wasn't any sql query done on the server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late come back.
I found what was the problem but don't completely understand it.
In the connect loop, I was using functions which were actually only simulating values (normally captured by a request). This was the problem. If you don't issue any database request in the pg.connect and loop on it, it seems the connections do not close properly. So the connection pool apparently breaks.
Hope I've been clear enough.

Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that the message of `sys.puts` may be incorrect - the server is only guaranteed to be listening once the (optional) callback function for `listen` fires. See: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#server.listen

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the async call "pg.connect" in a for loop.
Try this js module [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)